# How to create a flexible thumbnail grid of images with ng-repeat and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an array of objects (`imagesToDisplay`) containing the image uri (`image.tempURL`). I want to create a standard grid of thumbnails, as you have for instance on your iPhone in the phone library, using ng-repeat and flexible to the width of the viewer port.

The thumbnails should crop and center the image such that it fits the square thumnails.

I tried the following, but it didnt work...

**HTML**

```
<i ng-repeat="image in imagesToDisplay">
<img class="center-cropped" ng-src="{{image.tempURL}}" alt="Image">
</i>
```

**CSS**

```
.center-cropped {
  object-fit: none; /* Do not scale the image */
  object-position: center; /* Center the image within the element */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Basically, replace object-fit with

```
object-fit: cover;
```

The four possible values of object-fit are as [follows](https://dev.opera.com/articles/css3-object-fit-object-position/):

- contain: if you have set an explicit height and width on a replaced
  element, object-fit:contain will cause the content (e.g. the image)
  to be resized so that it is fully displayed with intrinsic aspect
  ratio preserved, but still fits inside the dimensions set for the
  element.
- fill: causes the element’s content to expand to completely
  fill the dimensions set for it, even if this does break its intrinsic
  aspect ratio.
- cover: preserves the intrinsic aspect ratio of the
  element content, but alters the width and height so that the content
  completely covers the element. The smaller of the two is made to fit
  the element exactly, and the larger overflows the element.
- none: the
  content completely ignorse any height or weight set on the element,
  and just uses the replaced element’s intrinsic dimensions.